# "Or" click function? Trying to avoid duplicate block of code

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create an "or" click function in Jquery? I have the following code, I want to create an additional button that does exactly the same when clicked... it seems inefficient to copy that block of code and just change the class at the start.

Can I do something like "if this class or this class is clicked"?

```
$(".close-page").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this).data('number');
    $( '.news-shift .full-page[data-number="' + item + '"]' ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $( '.news-close-x[data-number="' + item + '"]' ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('.revealed-news[data-number="' + item + '"]').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it this you mean `$(".close-page,.anotherclass").click`

Comment: Please elaborate more on your issue

Comment: Please just read the docs: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more classes to your selector separated by comma. Like this -

```
$(".close-page, .second-class, .third-class").click(function(e) {
```